# Fuzzy, nonsequential string search algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms

Is there an algorithm that can find `p + stuff` within `t`, where `stuff` is any set of characters, not just HTML markup?

Sample text *to search* (`t`):

```
some HTML markup Some text and <span>more</span> text <h3>and 
some more</h3> text in addition to <strong>more unknown text</strong>
```

Sample pattern *to find* (`p`):

```
Some text and more text and some more text
```

Is there an existing algorithm that can find `p + stuff` within `t`,

That is, the algorithm should return:

```
Some text and <span>more</span> text <h3>and some more</h3> text
```

*given an unknown set of HTML/other markup and characters*? The best I can describe this is `.` in regular expressions, any number of characters.

It sounds like Levenschtein distance is sort of what I'm looking for, but I haven't seen (or figured out) a way to use it in this way.

My current algorithm recursively tracks start and end indices, eventually narrowing `t` down to `p + stuff`, but I think it could be more efficient. The algorithm is also only *best match* since the set of `stuff` is unknown. I'm using a lot of regular expressions to estimate what could be in `t`. Maybe it's better to use an algorithm that works by-character instead of word?

Comment: From your example it seems like you can just ignore anything within angled brackets and use regular search.

Comment: @orlp And from the rest of my post, I indicate the set of characters is unknown.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Please edit the question to define what it means for p + markup/characters" to be within "t".  An example is not a substitute for a problem specification.  Don't make us guess.  (As you can see here -- without a specification, we are forced to guess what that means, precisely, and apparently the first guess was wrong -- but what is the right problem statement?)

Comment: Hunt&McIlroy (1976) http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.278.6540 . Myers(1986) http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.4.6927